# Is it possible to route calls to another webservice under servicestack v3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis, servicestack

We currently have a service stack v3 application set up as:

```
<location path="admin">
  <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, 
           ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

So any calls like http://localhost/resources/admin/task/hello/world go to the Servicestack rest service where **resources** is an IIS application where the service stack application is stored.

What I need to know is, is it possible to make a call such as http://localhost/resources/admin/task/remote which goes to a webservice outside of service stack? What I need to do is create an async web service which gets called outside of the servicestack calls.